# What to do when one wants to "revive" a question

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Prior to posting a question on MSE, I often find a similar question that's been asked, but doesn't have a solution I'm looking for or the solutions are written for a more mathematically mature person or for one of many other reasons. Sometimes I end up posting my question, but it still gets marked as a duplicate; other times I just end up not posting because I don't want to be associated with posting many duplicates.

I was thinking of a bounty, but to do so on several questions...Well, I don't have many rep points to begin with.

And I  don't want to edit the post just to bump it up as I know that can cause some moderators to be unhappy.

How then can I bring attention to the question?

I wasn't quite sure how to search for this type of question, so I hope this isn't a duplicate (no pun intended).

Comment: This seems related: [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer)

Comment: Is there a thread or something which summarizes what "irritates" the moderators? I would be curious about such information, and I don't think it is fully covered by the faq. For instance, I could not find there that it is not ok to edit old questions to bump them up, for whatever reason.

Comment: @julien: I don't think these things have much to do with the moderators themselves, it's more of what are the community norms regarding particular things. I don't think there is any codex of the sort.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can post your question, point out that a very similar one has been asked before but it does not contain the answer you are looking for.

Explain *why* it doesn't contain the answer you want, and also *what* sort of answer would satisfy you.

In such case I don't think your post would get closed as a duplicate, and if it does you can always ask for reopening on meta, by pointing out your explanation.